# NodeJS - Not being able to access the route I want

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having some troubles getting to a route I got. The route works on `http://localhost:3000/me` and shows info but on `http://localhost:3000/!#/me` it doenst show anything. The purpose of said route is to show the logged persons' profile.
On my server routes I got:

`app.get('/me', users.me);`

The `users.me` function is as follows:

`exports.me = function(req, res) {
    res.jsonp(req.user);
};`

The console states it expected a object and got an array, I can understand that since I'm getting a json, but how can I send the own user back to the front-end so it shows his/her profile?

**Edit:** I managed to solve my problem, since I use passportjs I can get the user id from the session. Since I already had a route for a user by id, I simply had to redirect to said route. Like this: `req.redirect('users/'+ req.session.passport.user);`. Since I already had a  `/users/:userId` route working it completely solved my issue.

**Edit2:** Apparently there are several ways to get the user id. Try to console.log the request and you will see what I mean :)

Comment: /me and /!#/me are not the same route . The later won't match get(' /me',..)

Comment: Yes I know but how come one works and the other one doesn't?
On the /me url I get the json output, and on the !#/me route I get the angular error:`[$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array`

Comment: What I could do is try to pass the logged user ID to the route and everything should work, but I don't know how to get the logged user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- /me and /!#/me are not the same route . The later won't match get('
  /me',..)
- the hash fragment **#/me** will not send to the server, you cannot capture that by server side routers(without force the page refresh by client code). But you can manage that by client-code.

Comment: Yes but how? I could do something else that is getting the id of the user that's logged in and pass it to a route: `/users/:userId` that works, my main problem is how can I get the id of the user logged.

Comment: Seems like it's not a problem with the route itself but with something else, I've tried the following code:
`app.get('/me', function(){});`
And on the chrome console I would get the exact same error (the expecting and object and getting an array error) as before on the angular, with I think there is something in between that angular is not liking it so much.

Comment: I agree and it also sounds like a separate question assuming I understand correctly: once the user is logged in and you can read from cookie or session variables. "I don't know how to get the logged user id"...do you know where the user id were stored once the user logged in? if that's clear, so will be the solution.

Comment: Well that's exactly my problem, I don't know where it's stored. But maybe the even bigger problem is me using mean.io, since it's an already programmed framework which has thing I don't know how they properly function, maybe I should start from scratch and build everything up, maybe I'll learn more and have less troubles. Thank you for the answers!